# Click on the Triangle project in P5.JS allows clicking outside of triangle fix

Tags: javascript, p5.js

Thank you so much for spending some of your day to try and help answer my problems!
I really appreciate it!!
I am new to P5JS but have decided to try it out!
My code is most likely not the most compact and I am grateful for any feed back you give!
My issue is, when you click on the part of the triangle that is outside of it, it seems that often it will accept that as inside of it.
I have most likely had an error in my code that allows this.
All my code is, is creating a random triangle in the canvas and testing for you to click or have a button held inside of the triangle.
When you do, it creates a new random one.
Please let me know what is making this odd error happen.
PS I used the online browser https://alpha.editor.p5js.org/ to run this so I would recommend running it in there to see it replicate this the best.

here is the code:

```
function setup() {
    createCanvas(500, 500);
    x1 = random(0, 500);
    y1 = random(0, 500);
    x2 = random(0, 500);
    y2 = random(0, 500);
    x3 = random(0, 500);
    y3 = random(0, 500);
    click = 0;
    x = false;
    y = false;
}
function testfor() {
    if (x == true && y == true) {
        if (mouseIsPressed) {
            click = 1;
        }
    }
    if (click == 1) {
        x1 = random(0, 500);
        y1 = random(0, 500);
        x2 = random(0, 500);
        y2 = random(0, 500);
        x3 = random(0, 500);
        y3 = random(0, 500);
        click = 0;
        X = false;
        Y = false;
    }
}
setInterval(testfor, 100);
function draw() {
    background(0, 100, 299);
    fill(125);
    triangle(x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3);
}
setInterval(draw, 100);
function xcheck() {
    if (x1 >= x2 && x1 >= x3) {
        if (x2 >= x3) {
            if (mouseX <= x1 && mouseX >= x3) {
                x = true;
            } else {
                x = false;
            }
        } else if (mouseX <= x1 && mouseX >= x2) {
            x = true;
        } else {
            x = false;
        }
    } else if (x2 >= x1 && x2 >= x3) {
        if (x1 >= x3) {
            if (mouseX <= x2 && mouseX >= x3) {
                x = true;
            } else {
                x = false;
            }
        } else if (mouseX <= x2 && mouseX >= x1) {
            x = true;
        } else {
            x = false;
        }
    } else if (x1 >= x2) {
        if (mouseX <= x3 && mouseX >= x2) {
            x = true;
        } else {
            x = false;
        }
    } else if (mouseX <= x3 && mouseX >= x1) {
        x = true;
    } else {
        x = false;
    }
}
setInterval(xcheck, 100);
function ycheck() {
    if (y1 >= y2 && y1 >= y3) {
        if (y2 >= y3) {
            if (mouseY <= y1 && mouseY >= y3) {
                y = true;
            } else {
                y = false;
            }
        } else if (mouseY <= y1 && mouseY >= y2) {
            y = true;
        } else {
            y = false;
        }
    } else if (y2 >= y1 && y2 >= y3) {
        if (y1 >= y3) {
            if (mouseY <= y2 && mouseY >= y3) {
                y = true;
            } else {
                y = false;
            }
        } else if (mouseY <= y2 && mouseY >= y1) {
            y = true;
        } else {
            y = false;
        }
    } else if (y1 >= y2) {
        if (mouseY <= y3 && mouseY >= y2) {
            y = true;
        } else {
            y = false;
        }
    } else if (mouseY <= y3 && mouseY >= y1) {
        y = true;
    } else {
        y = false;
    }
}
setInterval(ycheck, 100);
```

THANK you so much for your time!

Comment: You'll have much better luck if you post a [mcve] that just focuses on one thing. How about testing a single hard-coded point against a single hard-coded triangle?

Comment: Thank you Kevin Workman for you response but unfortunately I am not really sure how to do that, but could you maybe show me a sample code of what you mean? I apologize for not really understanding.  And if it was hard coded wouldn't that make it permanently using the same triangle? I am trying to use a new random triangle once the person clicks on the last triangle.  Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have made some modifications to your code.

To begin with, the `draw()` function is called automatically by the P5.js library, so you don't need to call `setInterval(draw, 100);`.

You also seem seem to be making many unnecessary checks, you only need to check for collisions WHEN the mouse is pressed. P5 makes this easy with the `mousePressed` function, which is called when the user clicks the mouse. This way you can get rid of the `click` variable and the `testFor` function, and move all collision checks inside of `mousePressed`.

```
function mousePressed() {
  xcheck();
  ycheck();

  if (x == true && y == true) {
    x1 = random(0, 500);
    y1 = random(0, 500);
    x2 = random(0, 500);
    y2 = random(0, 500);
    x3 = random(0, 500);
    y3 = random(0, 500);

    x = false;
    y = false;
  }
}
```

Now that we have optimized your code we can start to solve your original problem. We know the bug is inside `xcheck()` or `ycheck()` but i don't understand how your collision detection algorithm works, and i don't have the time to figure it out. You can try to find it yourself by `console.log()`ing different parts of your code: what is the value of `mouseX` when `mousePressed` is called? What is the value of `mouseY` when `mousePressed` is called? what is the output of `xcheck`? what is the output of `ycheck`? why is THAT the output? Answering these questions and making use of the Console will probably help you find your mistake.

What i can show you is a really simple point-to-triangle collision algorithm and how to implement it in your code. You can find how it works in the first 3 minutes of this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vvaczEyI0Ho There probably are better ways to do this, but this implementation is quite simple and easy to understand. The code would look like this:

```
function trianCollision(px, py, x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3) {

  // get the area of the triangle
  var areaOrig = floor(abs((x2 - x1) * (y3 - y1) - (x3 - x1) * (y2 - y1)));
  //console.log("totalArea: " + areaOrig);

  // get the area of 3 triangles made between the point and the corners of the triangle
  var area1 = floor(abs((x1 - px) * (y2 - py) - (x2 - px) * (y1 - py)));
  var area2 = floor(abs((x2 - px) * (y3 - py) - (x3 - px) * (y2 - py)));
  var area3 = floor(abs((x3 - px) * (y1 - py) - (x1 - px) * (y3 - py)));
  //console.log("areaSum: " + (area1 + area2 + area3));

  // if the sum of the three areas equals the original, we're inside the triangle
  if (area1 + area2 + area3 <= areaOrig) {
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

Putting it all together, your code should look like this:

```
function setup() {
  createCanvas(500, 500);

  x1 = random(0, 500);
  y1 = random(0, 500);
  x2 = random(0, 500);
  y2 = random(0, 500);
  x3 = random(0, 500);
  y3 = random(0, 500);

  x = false;
  y = false;
}

function draw() {
  background(202, 226, 249);
  fill(50);
  noStroke();
  triangle(x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3);
}

function mousePressed() {
  xcheck();
  ycheck();

  if (x == true && y == true) {
    x1 = random(0, 500);
    y1 = random(0, 500);
    x2 = random(0, 500);
    y2 = random(0, 500);
    x3 = random(0, 500);
    y3 = random(0, 500);

    x = false;
    y = false;
  }
}

function xcheck() {
  if (x1 >= x2 && x1 >= x3) {
    if (x2 >= x3) {
      if (mouseX <= x1 && mouseX >= x3) {
        x = true;
      } else {
        x = false;
      }
    } else if (mouseX <= x1 && mouseX >= x2) {
      x = true;
    } else {
      x = false;
    }
  } else if (x2 >= x1 && x2 >= x3) {
    if (x1 >= x3) {
      if (mouseX <= x2 && mouseX >= x3) {
        x = true;
      } else {
        x = false;
      }
    } else if (mouseX <= x2 && mouseX >= x1) {
      x = true;
    } else {
      x = false;
    }
  } else if (x1 >= x2) {
    if (mouseX <= x3 && mouseX >= x2) {
      x = true;
    } else {
      x = false;
    }
  } else if (mouseX <= x3 && mouseX >= x1) {
    x = true;
  } else {
    x = false;
  }
}


function ycheck() {
  if (y1 >= y2 && y1 >= y3) {
    if (y2 >= y3) {
      if (mouseY <= y1 && mouseY >= y3) {
        y = true;
      } else {
        y = false;
      }
    } else if (mouseY <= y1 && mouseY >= y2) {
      y = true;
    } else {
      y = false;
    }
  } else if (y2 >= y1 && y2 >= y3) {
    if (y1 >= y3) {
      if (mouseY <= y2 && mouseY >= y3) {
        y = true;
      } else {
        y = false;
      }
    } else if (mouseY <= y2 && mouseY >= y1) {
      y = true;
    } else {
      y = false;
    }
  } else if (y1 >= y2) {
    if (mouseY <= y3 && mouseY >= y2) {
      y = true;
    } else {
      y = false;
    }
  } else if (mouseY <= y3 && mouseY >= y1) {
    y = true;
  } else {
    y = false;
  }
}
```

If you want to use the other algorithm just say

```
function mousePressed() {

  if (trianCollision(mouseX, mouseY, x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3)) {
    x1 = random(0, 500);
    y1 = random(0, 500);
    x2 = random(0, 500);
    y2 = random(0, 500);
    x3 = random(0, 500);
    y3 = random(0, 500);

    x = false;
    y = false;
  }
}
```

I hope this helps you in some way, and feel free to ask if you have any questions.

Comment: OMG thank you for simplifying this so much!  I am so glad that you spent some time looking at my issue!  The only issue is that I can still click outside of the triangle like quite outside and it often still accepts it as inside of the triangle.  I will look into it some more and hope to fix it!! :)